# Retrieved item iterated instead adding new value

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I'm retrieving data from `JSON` like below :

```
worker: [{
    content: "android"
}, {
    content: "java"
}]
```

So I supposed that I will see values (android, java) but it doesn't happen i only see java iterated :

[image]

And this my way to get this length of array I retrieved from `JSON`:

I get the array correctly and pass it with `SharedPreference` :

```
JSONArray workerArr = object.getJSONArray("worker");
String jsonString = workerArr.toString();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("jsonString", jsonString);
editor.commit();
```

Then I get this length by this way simply :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
String jsonString = settings.getString("jsonString", null);
JSONArray jsonArray = null;
try {
    jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    Log.i(TAG, "displayCommentsJsonArray: " + jsonArray);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is how i add retrieved item to list...

```
List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
if (jsonArray != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        String value = "";
        value = mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.WORKERS);
        top250.add(value);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);
    }
}
```

So i should see two values in my list instead of same values with same count of array..

i don't know what i missed?

my `mCursor` throw this value in log :

> prepareListData: java prepareListData: java

Comment: your updating the different value with same key

Comment: You can get the value directly from jsonArray.                                        
        String value = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("content"); top250.append(value);                And I think you should put this line out of for loop: listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);

Comment: are you reffereing to `mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.WORKERS)` ?

Comment: Please, check whether you are updating  mCursor's pointer for every iteration.

Comment: @minhazur check update please, it's throw same value "java"

Comment: @Sac thnx your simple solution worked !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating the `jsonArray`, but I can't see any code where you parse the data from it.

Move the `listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);` outside the loop. (As **@Sac** pointed)

Try the code below.

```
if (jsonArray != null) {
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String value = object.getString("content");
        top250.add(value);
    }
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);
}
```

I don't know the content of `mCursor` variable.